# Return to a specific Fragment from a different Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making a shopping app using android. I'm currently on the product details *Activity* and i want to return to my **Home Activity** with my Product Fragments listing all the Products instead of going back to my **Home Activity**.

I've tried using `super.OnBackPressed()`.. and it works however I'm not sure if it's actually a good practice?

```
 backbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ProductDetailActivity.super.OnBackPressed();
                }
            });
```

Comment: while launching your product detail page have you finished your HomeActivity?

Comment: nope i started the product detail activity directly

Comment: You started ProductDetail from your ProductFragment Listing which is in HomeActivity?

Comment: yup, and when i use the super.OnBackPressed() it works like how i want it to be... it's just that... I'm not sure that it's a good practice to do it this way.

Comment: In my opinion there is no problem if you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend using library that is part of Android Jetpack - Navigation component.
Some additional links [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation), [Udacity](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9012/lessons/7466f670-3d47-4b60-8f6a-0914ce58f9ad/concepts/43ef25c1-2694-462c-8864-10ed7531c05a)